# Python Fuzzy Matches in two text files

Tags: python, fuzzy-search

I’ve got a simple bit of code that matches network usernames found in two text files. I’ve tried to normalize the input by changing both inputs to uppercase, but I need to take it a stage further and get my code to produce partial matches of usernames. I may have SMITH, JOHN in one list, and perhaps, SMITH,JOHN (FINANCE) in another list. I’ve looked at FuzzyWuzzy but I’ve only been learning Python for a couple of weeks, and I’m struggling to understand how to use it in my script.

```
with OpenUpperCase(filename, "r")as file1:
    for line in islice(file1,20,None):
        with OpenUpperCase ("c:\\Files\Usernames.txt", "r") as file2:
            files= filename.upper().split("\\")
            int1=files[3].strip()
            filedate=int1[0:-4]
            list2 = file2.readlines()
            for i in file1:
                for j in list2:
                    if i == j:
```

This is what I have so far, not great coding probably, but it seems to work. Any thoughts as to how I can get a fuzzy match of my usernames please? 
Many thanks for any help you could provide.

**EDIT.**

Typically, my lists will look like this. Obviously with hundreds of users.

File1

```
Salt, William (old user)
Wilds, Tony
Smith, William (Old User)
JONES,Steven (Old User)
```

File2

```
Salt, Bill
Wilds, Tony (SALES)
Smith,Will (OLD USER)
JONES,STEVEN (ACCOUNTS)
```

Comment: Could you give a sample of your lists?

Comment: @zhangyangyu lists attached to give you an idea.

Comment: thanks @Mike Müller for the edit into a more readable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stringIO` objects for simplicity:

```
file1 = io.StringIO("""Salt, William (old user)
Wilds, Tony
Smith, William (Old User)
JONES,Steven (Old User)""")

file2 = io.StringIO("""Salt, Bill
Wilds, Tony (SALES)
Smith,Will (OLD USER)
JONES,STEVEN (ACCOUNTS)""")
```

Read all names into a set:

```
def read_file(fobj):
    names = set()
    for line in fobj:
        split_line = line.lower().split(',')
        names.add((split_line[0], split_line[1].split()[0]))
    return names
```

For each file:

```
data1 = read_file(file1)
data2 = read_file(file2)
```

A simple intersection will do:

```
data1.intersection(data2)
```

Result:

```
set([('wilds', 'tony'), ('jones', 'steven')])
```

Comment: This is big help. Thanks @Mike Müller